# Regexp: count amount of quotes before matched string

Tags: regex, expression, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, oniguruma

Let's say I have a string I want to match: **banana**. The problem is that I want to check whether this string is inside of double quotes. I've read that you can count the amount of double quotes in the whole line:

```
(?<!')banana(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$).*$
```

However it doesn't match that string if I have input such as this:

```
"nope" banana "
```

In this case I still want the string to be matched (avoid nested quotes), so it means I need to count amount of double quotes BEFORE the string. How can I do that? 
P.S. I use onigurama in vscode extension

Answer (score 0):

As I understand a question you need something like this: `\G(?>".*?"|.)*?\Kbanana`

Comment: If I haven't made that clear, I want a regex which matches word banana if the amount of double quotes before this word is even. Your one doesn't seem to work

Comment: "Your one doesn't seem to work".  Here is a test: https://regex101.com/r/2m0MGE/2  What subject string not matched by this regex?

Comment: I meant it doesn't work in my onigurama vscode environment